# Is it possible to index a NumPy array with a boolean expression?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Suppose I have the following array:

```
a = np.array([0,1,0],
             [1,0,0],
             [0,0,1])
```

Would it be possible to do something like the this:

```
a[==0] = -1
```

to set all zeros to -1? I know you could something like the following to achieve the same effect:

```
b = a == 0
a[b] = -1
```

but I was just wondering if there was a way to skip the creation of the Boolean array for this.

Comment: Not with boolean indexing, which by definition needs that boolean array. But alternatively : `2*a-1` for such an array of 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax was almost correct. This seems to work:

```
a[a == 0] = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

using `np.where`

```
np.where(a==0, -1, a)
```